# Translate all magento1.9.2 emails in French language

Tags: magento-1.9

We are running mangento1.9.2 website which contains two stores i-e English and French.

Now all the emails sent to users are only in English language but if the users in French store then email should be sent in French language.

Kindly guide me that how can I translate the magento emails into French.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create the template Email that you want to send in frensh language in: `app/locale/fr_FR` and the Email Will be sent in frensh language if a store is set in frensh.